# Standard deviation of $Z = 9 - 3Y^3$

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

If Y is a random variable with probability mass function:

```
 Y | Pr(Y = y)
-1 | 0.4
 0 | 0.5
 1 | 0.1
```

I need to find the standard deviation of $Z = 9 - 3Y^3$.

Approach: since it's the variance I know that 9 should not affect it and I essentially have $3^2 Var(Y^3)$ using one of the identities.  My understanding is that I should be able to use the delta method to find $Var(Y^3)$ but I am not sure how.  I don't think I can directly use the identity $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ can I?

Comment: Hint: what is the distribution of $Y^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(-1)^3=-1$, $0^3=0$, and $1^3=1$, $Y^3$ has the same distribution as $Y$. Therefore
$$\mathrm{Var}(9-3Y^3) = 3^2\mathrm{Var}(Y^3) = 9\mathrm{Var}(Y). $$
Since
$$\mathrm{Var}(Y) = \mathbb E[Y^2] - \mathbb E[Y]^2 = \frac12 - \left(\frac3{10}\right)^2 = \frac{41}{100},$$
it follows that $$\mathrm{Var}(Z) = 9\cdot\frac{41}{100} = \frac{369}{100}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can transform the random variable.

```
  Z | Pr(Y = y)
    12 | 0.4
     9 | 0.5
     6 | 0.1
```

Now you can calculate $Var(Z)$ directly.

**Update**

The straightforward calculation is

$$Var(Z)=0.4\cdot (12-9.9)^2+0.5 \cdot  (9-9.9)^2+0.1 \cdot  (6-9.9)^2=3.69$$

Comment: Wow that was simpler that I expected, thanks!

Comment: The simpler, the better. You are welcome.